# Android send mail not focus on the email's body automatically

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

I have question about send mail, how disable focus text with Intent.ACTION_SEND

Is it possible to:

**1) Not focus on the email's body automatically**

**2) Focus on the top of the email**

----> help me :
Code send Mail :

```
 String to = "aaaaa@gmail.com";
        String subject = "bbbbbb";
        //Intent action send
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.setType("text/plain");
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                       new String[]{to});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                       subject);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");


        //need this to prompts email client only
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(email,
                                                                  "Send mail..."),
                                             12345);
```

It image :[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to: 1) Not focus on the email's body automatically 2) Focus on the top of the email

No, that is not possible, because *you did not write the email app*. That app was written by other programmers, and those programmers are welcome to do whatever they want. What part of their compose-message UI is focused is up to them, not you.

Moreover, the behavior that you will see will depend on the email client. There are many email client apps for Android; not all are written the same.